# How can a webpack loader know that it is the final loader in a chain?

Tags: webpack

I am writing a webpack loader that should work whether is it the last one in a chain (of loaders), or in the middle – thus returning a function instead of a JavaScript string.

How can the loader know that it is the final one in chain?

Or is this a bad idea such that all loaders must always return a JS string?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `this.options` inside of your custom loader will return the webpack configuration object. So you can use that to access `this.options.module.loaders` to determine the order of the loaders and which loader is last/first/etc.

You can read more about the LoaderAPI [here.](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#options)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [`loader-utils`](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/blob/master/index.js#L146) package.

Not exactly certain, but I think this might help you understand where your loader is in the chain.

```
// @module loaders/foo
export default function(source, inputSourceMap) {
  const remaning = loaderUtils.getRemainingRequest(this).split('!');
};
```